# Calendar Overlays

Tags: 2013, calendar, overlay

I've got about 9 calendars overlaying at the moment, I want to make it easier for less computer minded staff to turn these calendars on and off from view.

Is there a way for me to put some simple checkboxes above the calendar view to enable/disable certain calendars from view?

We have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, there are some restrictions stopping me altering master pages.

Comment: I've tried making a link above it to the page where you turn on/off the overlays, but it has a bug where if you do it a second time, when you click OK, it redirects you to a 'Something Went Wrong' page. The url has doubled on itself

EG: https://collab.web.spsite.com/sites/site_title/_layouts/15/https://collab.web.spsite.com/sites/site_title/SitePages/All%20Calendars.aspx

Notice how the URL is double.

Comment: Also tried copying the HTML element for the 'Calendar Overlays' button and pasting within an 'Embed Code' snippet, but the JavaScript doesn't seem to work.

Comment: use jquery toggle() and put each calendar in a seperate div. and a button or check box on for it. on click of every button/checkbox you can show or hide the entire dive for that calendar.